# SSRS Displaying Comma Delimited or Distinct Values in Single Column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a relationship like this:

[image]

I'd like to display the Acctnbr field in SSRS like this as a single field:

[image]

I have tried expressions like this

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!Baseacctnbr.Value, 
    Fields!Baseacctnbr.Value, 
    Fields!Acctnbr.Value, 
    "DataSet1"), ",")
```

and I get an error message that reads:

> Aggregate, Rownumber, runningvalue, previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

I can get the comma delimited field from SQL using the STUFF function, but my SSRS report is grouping and when I group I loose the SQL code.

How can I get this to work?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using that expression in a calculated field? You are using any of the error listed functions in a calculated field expression. The expression you are trying should work in a cell

Comment: Yes, I'm using this expression in a calculated field.  I'm using SQl 2008 R2 and VS 2012.

Comment: Don't use it as calculated field, use it in your column. If you need further help I'll post an answer.

Comment: Ok, please provide more details of what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this dataset to test I recreated your scenario.

[image]

Try using your expression in a column of your tablix:

[image]

I've added the expression you posted in the cell is highlighted.

It will preview the following table.

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: I'm getting a different error message now.  "The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of the dataset."

Comment: I think I got it.  I had to change the expression slightly to capitalize the dataset from dataset1 to DataSet1 =join(LookupSet(Fields!baseacctnbr.value,(Fields!baseacctnbr.Value,Fields!acctnbr.Value,**"DataSet1"**), ",")